# Search by samaccountname in people picker

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-service

Our current people picker works perfect, but we have about 5000 users and it would be easier for us to use the samaccountname which comes from AD.

Is it possible to do?

Comment: I have requested to delete this question, I will come back later with all the info about the membership providers as I dont have access to the environment yet, I will ask this again in a few days.

Comment: I have closed the question for the time being, rather than delete it, as requested. Esteban: Please update the question and flag for moderator attention when ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

default you can insert the samaccountname from ad in a people picker ?
After resolving it will show the Full Name, but does that even matter ?

5000 AD users is not much... I'm working in an environment with +20000 users, and we still use it like that.

Im wondering, is ur question: how to display samaccountname instead of fullname?
Or is it, how to be able to insert users using samaccountname?

Comment: indeed, its how to be able to search by username, I dont mind if after searching it displays the full name, but when searching it should be possible to search by the username .

Comment: So this is not working yet? Is this a custom aspx page? Or the default people picker in a default sharepoint page ?

Comment: its the default people picker!!!!

Comment: so you are using a default people picker which you are unable to search users by samaccountname? Thats strange. Since default this is possible. Have you changed anything to your membership providers on this webapplication?

Answer (score 0):

I found this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rajank/archive/2009/09/01/all-you-want-to-know-about-people-picker-in-sharepoint-functionality-configuration-troubleshooting-part-1.aspx

If you succeed, please give us feedback, I'm also interested by this.